# Problems with html5 sectioning elements

Tags: html, css

So I'm having problems with HTML5 sectioning elements. It seems that I have to create containers, otherwise they are't block level. I did add a CSS reset, so I don't know if that is causing it. Not sure if I should put my full code in. I want to make sure it doesn't have extra code that I don't need.

Anyway here is part of the html5:

`<div class="wrapper"><nav><ul>`
`<li><a href="#">About</a></li>`
`<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>`
`<li><a href="#">Content</a></li>`
`</ul>`
`</nav>`
`</div>`

If I didn't have that wrapper, for whatever reason, it would not treat it like a block quote.

Comment: This happens in all browsers?

Comment: @JosephSilber Actually, most browsers right now *do* have default styling on the HTML5 elements.  It just happens to be as benign as `header, footer, nav /* etc */ { display: block }`.  Only older browsers don't, and certain older IEs don't even let you style *unrecognized* HTML elements.

Comment: @cimmanon - True. In IE, you just have to create those elements in JS. There's even the [`HTML5shiv`](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) that creates them all for you.

Comment: It's happening in Safari. I haven't tested other browsers yet. Perhaps my question is, why isn't nav acting like a block.

Comment: you have tried adding a css rule display: block to all html5 elements?

Comment: When you inspect the <nav> to view its CSS (e.g: through Chrome's developer tools, rightclick and inspect element), does it still say display:block?

Answer (score 1):

Minimal version of the browser wich support HTML5 semantic elements: IE 9, Firefox 4, Chrome 8, Safari 5, Opera 11.1, Safari iOS 4, Android 2.1.

If you are using older browsers version, the browser will be build all unrecognized elements as inline elements. To fix this problem, you simply need to add a new rule to your CSS:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

This CSS rule will have not negative affect for browsers who recognize HTML5, because property 'display' is already set to 'block'.

Old versions of IE (<9) have another problems. They refuse to apply CSS rules formatting to elements wich they don’t recognize. To fix it:

```
<script>
    document.createElement('article');
    document.createElement('aside');
    ...
    document.createElement('section');        
</script>
```

Or if you don't want write code for all elements, you can use this script: [html5shiv.js](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/). Also, you will be interested: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)